# Nginx warning: client sent invalid header line: "server_port: 80" while reading client request headers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx instance `proxy_pass`ing an HTTP request to an HTTPS API. These some configs like:

```
# some $args rewrites and headers

proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_set_header Host $target_host;
proxy_pass https://my-host/api$uri$is_args$args;
```

But I found this error when deployed in containers. Full error looks like:

```
2023/02/03 15:22:29 [info] 21#21: *40 client sent invalid header line: "server_port: 80" while reading client request headers, client: XXXXXXX, server: , request: "POST /XXXXXXX/XXXXX?XXXXXXXX=XXXX HTTP/1.1", host: "XXXXX.XXXX.com"
```

Comment: That's not an error, just an info. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Underscores in header names are generally not allowed. So either find out why your application is sending a header called `server_port` and change the name, or instruct the servers which receive the request to allow [underscores in headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers).